# ¿Como modifico el valor global de tabindex? o ¿Cómo hacer que el foco vaya al siguiente elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

En este ejemplo cuando pulsas en un `textarea` se te abre otro más grande para escribir más cómodamente y luego cuando pierde el foco pasa todo la info a al textarea original.

El problema es que quiero que cuando el `textarea` grade pierda el foco, ya sea porque he pinchado fuera o porque he pulsado tabulación, el foco lo gane el siguiente `textarea`.

```js
var componente;
$(".text").focus(function() {
  console.log('ll');
  $("#padre").css("filter", "blur(4px)");
  $("#wraperTextArea").show();
  $("#textOver").focus();
  var texto = $(this).val();
  componente = $(this);
  $("#labelOver").html($(this).data('label'));
  $("#textOver").attr('tabindex', $(this).attr('tabindex') + 1);
  $("#textOver").val(texto);
});
$("#textOver").blur(function() {
  $("#padre").css("filter", "blur(0)");
  $("#wraperTextArea").hide();
  var texto = $(this).val();
  componente.val(texto);
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#padre {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #5ecab3;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#padre>* {
  background: #feb2a8;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

label {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
}

#wraperTextArea {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid;
  padding: 10vh 10vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  display: none;
}

textarea#textOver {
  height: calc(90% - 5rem);
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
}

#labelOver {
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='padre'>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Nombre</label>
    <textarea data-label="nombre" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Apellidos</label>
    <textarea data-label="Apellidos" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Edad</label>
    <textarea data-label="Edad" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='wraperTextArea'>
  <label id="labelOver" for="text">aqui el texto</label>
  <textarea name="text" id="textOver" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

¿Como modifico el valor global de `tabindex`?

Toda la información que encuentro habla del valor del atributo `tabindex` de los elementos, pero no del valor global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En respuesta a:

> [...]o ¿Cómo hacer que el foco vaya al siguiente elemento?

Para que al presionar <kbd>Tab</kbd> vaya al siguiente elemento, solo tienes que:

- A los `textarea` "chicos" agregarles un `tabindex` diferente y en orden ascendente. Esto le indicará al navegador cual es el elemento al que se le debe dar foco a continuación del elemento actual.
- Al mostrar y darle foco al `textarea` "grande", le asignamos el mismo `tabindex` que tiene el elemento que disparó el evento.

Para que al presionar <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> se le de foco al elemento anterior, podemos:

- Suscribirnos al evento `keydown` del `textarea` "grande", detectar que dichas teclas están siendo presionadas, buscar el elemento con `tabindex` menor al del elemento y darle foco.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var componente;
$(".text").focus(function() {
  $("#padre").css("filter", "blur(4px)");
  $("#wraperTextArea").show();
  $("#textOver").focus();
  componente = $(this);
  $("#labelOver").html($(this).data('label'));
  $("#textOver").attr('tabindex', $(this).attr('tabindex'));
  $("#textOver").val($(this).val());
});
$("#textOver").blur(function() {
  $("#padre").css("filter", "blur(0)");
  $("#wraperTextArea").hide();
  componente.val($(this).val());
});
$("#textOver").on('keydown', function(evt) {
  if (evt.shiftKey && evt.key == 'Tab') {
    $('.text[tabindex="'+($(this).prop('tabindex') - 1)+'"]').focus();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#padre {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #5ecab3;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#padre>* {
  background: #feb2a8;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
label {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
}
#wraperTextArea {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid;
  padding: 10vh 10vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  display: none;
}
textarea#textOver {
  height: calc(90% - 5rem);
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
}
#labelOver {
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='padre'>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Nombre</label>
    <textarea data-label="Nombre" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10" tabindex="1"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Apellidos</label>
    <textarea data-label="Apellidos" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10" tabindex="2"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="text">Edad</label>
    <textarea data-label="Edad" name="text" class="text" cols="30" rows="10" tabindex="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='wraperTextArea'>
  <label id="labelOver" for="text">aqui el texto</label>
  <textarea name="text" id="textOver" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Pues ya lo había intentado y no me había salido... algo escribí mal.

Comment: @E.rick, he actualizado mi respuesta, para dar una solución un poco mas completa.